# Getting the Roles of the current user in .NET Core2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I use usermanager.GetUserName(User) to get the username of the current user, but there is no GetUserRole for usermanager.
How can I retrieve the Roles of the user in .NET Core2.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(User)`:  Gets a list of role names the specified user belongs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserManager` has `GetRolesAsync()` method, which gets a list of role names the specified user belongs to.

```
var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```